# Why does creating an inclusive range use ..= while matching on an inclusive range uses ...?

Tags: rust, range

[Ranges use `..=` for inclusive range](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/flow_control/for.html):

```
for n in 1..=100 {
    if n % 15 == 0 {
        println!("fizzbuzz");
    } else if n % 3 == 0 {
        println!("fizz");
    } else if n % 5 == 0 {
        println!("buzz");
    } else {
        println!("{}", n);
    }
}
```

While [match uses `...` for inclusive range](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/flow_control/match.html):

```
match number {
    // Match a single value
    1 => println!("One!"),
    // Match several values
    2 | 3 | 5 | 7 | 11 => println!("This is a prime"),
    // Match an inclusive range
    13...19 => println!("A teen"),
    // Handle the rest of cases
    _ => println!("Ain't special"),
}
```

Comment: *Rust match uses `...` for inclusive range* — it doesn't have to and that syntax is effectively deprecated.

Comment: thanks. I've read the linked messages above.